# ImageIcon showing as grey

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I am new to flutter and trying to load some custom images into my project and convert them into icons. The images are stored in firebase storage but I have included the url for each image in my database. When I try and load each image in and convert them to icons, they turn grey. Here is the code...

```
class BodyOne extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyOneState createState() => _BodyOneState();
}

class _BodyOneState extends State<BodyOne> {
  Future getEvents() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection('events').getDocuments();

    return qn.documents;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getEvents(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Loading...'),
            );
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  leading: ImageIcon(
                    NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index].data['img_url']),
                  ),
                  title: Align(
                    child: TitleText(
                        title: snapshot.data[index].data['eventName']),
                    alignment: Alignment(-1.2, 0),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is what it returns:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do this, rather, just use your [Image class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html) and give `height` and `width` to the data.

```
leading: Image(
  image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index].data['img_url']),
  width: your_width,
  height: your_height,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  color: null // this is the work around
)
```